# Why do I get assembly bind failure in IIS CGI program

Tags: c#, .net, iis, cgi, assembly-resolution

I have a C# program that is running as a CGI app in IIS on XP Pro SP3. It runs fine until I reference a library assembly class and use it in the program's code. If I run the CGI program by hand it loads and executes. But when it is run by IIS the referenced assembly fails to bind despite it being right in the same directory as the parent executable. Here's the binding log I get:

```
=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = STEVIENEW\IUSR_STEVIENEW
LOG: DisplayName = VOEvent, Version=3.0.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file://?/C:/Documents and Settings/Robert B. Denny/My Documents/iis/vomsgtst/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
Calling assembly : MsgChkCGI, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: No application configuration file found.
LOG: Using machine configuration file from c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file://?/C:/Documents and Settings/Robert B. Denny/My Documents/iis/vomsgtst/VOEvent.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file://?/C:/Documents and Settings/Robert B. Denny/My Documents/iis/vomsgtst/VOEvent/VOEvent.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file://?/C:/Documents and Settings/Robert B. Denny/My Documents/iis/vomsgtst/VOEvent.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file://?/C:/Documents and Settings/Robert B. Denny/My Documents/iis/vomsgtst/VOEvent/VOEvent.EXE.
```

The Appbase is correct (though what is the '?' in the URI????? maybe that's a hint). The assembly voevent.dll is definitely right in the same directory (Appbase!) as MsgChkCGI.exe. And if I just double click the exe it stsrts up correctly (and has an error due to a missing CGI environment var, but that's expected).

Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: Very strange, the fusion binder can't even find the MsgChkCGI.exe.config file I put there! I tried adding assemblyBInding info to that with the exact path/version of the assembly. It can't even find the @#$%^ app.config file! What Up?

Comment: That question mark in the path is a red flag.

Comment: Data point: I tried this CGI under my venerable O'Reilly WebSite Pro server, also on XP Pro, and it runs fine!!! So this is a problem that is specific to IIS and it's handling of CGI programs that run under the .NET CLR. I need to solve it because this CGI needs to run on my IIS system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why the might happen.

As a workaround, you could handle [`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve.aspx)

**EDIT**: Note that if you use types from another assembly in the same method that adds the handler, the event won't fire, because the assembly will be loaded by the JITter before the code in the method is actually executed.
Therefore, you need to put any code that uses types from other assemblies in a separate method, then call that method after handling `AssemblyResolve`.

**2<sup>nd</sup> EDIT**: Call `Assembly.Load(File.ReadAllBytes(path))`.
Also, can you edit your question to include all of the details of the `FileNotFoundException` from `Assembly.LoadFile`?

Comment: It appears that this event is never fired. The problem appears to happen before the program starts to execute, not when it first tries to create a type in that referenced assembly. Thanks for trying though!

Comment: Add the handler, then put _all_ of your code in a separate function and call it after the handler.  It _will_ work.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try. I appreciate your persistence :-) Er, I assume you mean to add the handler to the event in Main(), then call a function which contains the entire rest of the program right after that.

Comment: It's getting hit. Now for the amazing part: I use ResolveEventArgs to identify which assembly it's trying to resolve (it is the fully qualified assy name) and construct a path to the assembly file. Then I call File.Exists() on that path, it returns true. I then use the exact same path (a string variable) in a call to Assembly.LoadFile() and it throws a System.IO.FileNotFoundException!! See above, this runs on Windows on a non-IIS webserver without jumping through these hoops. This is something being done by IIS!

Comment: @bob: yeah, .net has a very "interesting" usage of the FNF exception there. This can also mean that one of the dependencies is not found. Enable the Fusion log to get details.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the SLaks answer, I've written the solution

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
Uri codeBaseUrl = new Uri(assembly.CodeBase);
// hack IIS CGI malformed url
if (codeBaseUrl.ToString().StartsWith("file:///?/"))
    codeBaseUrl = new Uri("file:///" + codeBaseUrl.ToString().Substring(10));
string dir = Uri.UnescapeDataString(codeBaseUrl.AbsolutePath);
dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(dir);

AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (sender, args) =>
{
    var dllName = new AssemblyName(args.Name).Name + ".dll";
    dllName = Path.Combine(dir, dllName);

    return Assembly.LoadFile(dllName);
};
```

However, other parts of .NET fails due to the malformed URL `file:///?/`, so I would like to know the solution how to force not to change the URL.pass the normal URL

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to start the process with the EXE from another CGI, e.g. from PHP, anotehr EXE or CMD.

To use the *.cmd as CGI, type a simple CMD script which runs the EXE

```sh
@echo off
%~dp0\myprogram.exe
```

And configure the IIS to run CMD as CGI. Do the same as for the EXE file, just type your CMD in the proper settings. Then go to the *Handler Mappings*, choose *CGI-exe* and change the `*.exe` to `*.cmd`. Finally go to the CGI panel and change the *Use new console...* to **True**.